# It Take too much time to drag marker on google map

Tags: android, google-maps, drag-and-drop, google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2

I am working on google map api v2, and i want to make my marker draggable true,
Simply i want to drag my marker from a location and drop it on anonther one, but it taking time to focus on that marker.

Following is my code, plz suggest me where I'm doing wrong

**Activity :**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class DragMarker extends FragmentActivity implements OnMarkerDragListener {

    private static GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstance) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_drag_marker);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);

        //map.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
        //      map.setOnMapClickListener(this);

        CameraPosition INIT = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(19.0222, 72.8666)).zoom(17.5F).bearing(300F) // orientation
                .tilt(50F) // viewing angle
                .build();

        // use map to move camera into position
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(INIT));

        //create initial marker
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(19.0216, 72.8646)).draggable(true).title("Location").snippet("First Marker")).showInfoWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LatLng dragPosition = arg0.getPosition();
        double dragLat = dragPosition.latitude;
        double dragLong = dragPosition.longitude;
        Log.i("info", "on drag end :" + dragLat + " dragLong :" + dragLong);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Marker Dragged..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /*@Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(arg0));
    }*/

    /*@Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //create new marker when user long clicks
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(arg0).draggable(true));
    }*/
}
```

**XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: i have d same problem did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Put the marker draggable:

```
Marker perth = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(PERTH).draggable(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

// Creating MarkerOptions

```
           MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
```

// Setting the position of the marker

```
           options.position(point);
```

//set marker dragable true

```
           options.draggable(true);
```